# What is the alternative for bccmd?

Tags: utilities, bluez

I  am trying to learn about Bluetooth stack. In many blogs, they mention a tool called **bccmd**. But when I download the package bluez and compile it, I didn't found it. It seems it was in the  tools folder.
Can someone tell me if there is an alternative for it in this package or other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command was [removed from sources in 2020-09](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?h=5.64&id=e2e198ced468122df7b431cb06158123ba60a2f2):

> tools: Remove legacy code for CSR controllers
>
> This code has not been touched for ages and very unlikely that someone
> will be using this nowadays as most of these controller specific
> transports are handled by the kernel nowadays.

Chances are you are looking at outdated blogs, but I wouldn't know on this topic.

You just need an older version if you really need it.
Example: Debian 11 still [provides it](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/bluez/bccmd.1), because its package is based on version 5.55 from (right) before its removal.

So if you want last upstream release that provided it, you could clone the adequate git repository:

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch=5.55 https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git
```

Or download it from there (as seen in http://www.bluez.org/ ): https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.55.tar.xz

Comment: Oh thank you, i got the idea from you comment,  i was experimenting ;). thank you for the help.